# Validations on models for a sports league

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation

The schema question has been asked before and the below is a snapshot of what I believe is right. The issue I'm having now is getting a validation to work so that the same two players don't play more than once in a division. For starters we have three different inserts happening:

- Create match
- Create result_1 (whoever submitted)
- Create result_2

So the results can come in any order (dependent on who submitted) and aren't in the same record which would have made looking for a duplicate easier.

```
Match
- division_id


Result
- match_id
- player_id
- score
```

Is the only way around this to write a separate validation by taking the player_id's and comparing them in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data you're validating against lives in the database, then you need to go to the database, yes.